# Excel AverageIf to get total average of multiple rows from a table

Tags: excel

I have provided a simple example of what I would like to do. I tried to use `AverageIf` to get the average of all Monday sales for March and April but the formula only provides me the average of March's Monday sales and excludes April.

Note: `Column A is Weekday number, Column B is March Sales, Column C is April Sales.`

This is the formula I used:

`=AVERAGEIF(A2:A200, "=" & 1, B2:C200)`, which only provides me with average Monday sales in column B.

How can I adjust the formula to also include April in the total average (i.e. take into account column C rather than just column B alone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `AverageIf()`, try using `Average(If())` as an array formula for this kind of scenario.

In your scenario, you could use the following formula to get the average:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A2:A200=1,B2:C200))
```

**ENTERED AS AN ARRAY FORMULA** using <kbd>cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Hope that helps.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the help! This worked very well. I still wonder why the formula I was using didn't work.